# deselectrowatindexpath text highlighting gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

i am setting the `detailTextLabel` of an `UITableViewCell` to `highlighted:YES;`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

But for what reason `deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` is destroying the highlighting of my `detailTextLabel`?!

UPDATE:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row != 0)
{

    if(CellIsSelected)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setHighlighted:NO];
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if ([self datePickerIsShown] && (self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row)){

        [self hideExistingPicker];

    }else {

        NSIndexPath *newPickerIndexPath = [self calculateIndexPathForNewPicker:indexPath];

        if ([self datePickerIsShown]){

            [self hideExistingPicker];

            selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

            if (newPickerIndexPath.row == 2)
                selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:indexPath.section];
            else if (newPickerIndexPath.row == 3)
                selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:indexPath.section];

        }
        else
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

        [self showNewPickerAtIndex:newPickerIndexPath];

        self.datePickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newPickerIndexPath.row + 1 inSection:0];

    }

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    CellIsSelected = YES;

    [picker reloadAllComponents];


}
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kOtherCellID];

cell.textLabel.text = text;

if(CellIsSelected)
    [cell.detailTextLabel setHighlighted:YES];
else
    [cell.detailTextLabel setHighlighted:NO];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: u want detailTextLabel always to be highlighted...? explain in detail

Comment: if i click on a cell i want the cell to be highlighted(only for the moment) and my detailTextLabel should stay highlighted...like in the iOS 7 Calendar App...

Comment: How you are getting `selectedIndexPath`? Put that code too

Comment: From didSelectRowAtIndexPath Delegate...

Comment: now u just replaced `selectedIndexPath` with `indexPath`:)

Comment: Yes i did...Was a writing issue...

Comment: Not sure why this is happening. But if you set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate and remove `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` it will keep `detailTextLabel` highlighted.

Comment: Yes, that works. But it destroys the other visual effect UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray just for the Click...Like I said, just like in the calendar App

Comment: ok what about `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [discountLabel setHighlighted:YES];
    });`

Comment: @chrizstone i edited the code please check it

Comment: @chrizstone i edited and also i posted the gif image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one way for your requirement 
i am posting the sample code try this in new project,try it hope this helps u

in `ViewController.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
@end
```

in `ViewController.m` file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
   BOOL isCellSelected;
} 

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize selectedIndexPath = _selectedIndexPath;
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
    isCellSelected = NO;
    _selectedIndexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc]init];
 }
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return 5;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"EXAMPLE";
    cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //check if higlight is remains same or not

    if(isCellSelected)
       [cell.detailTextLabel setHighlighted:YES];
    else
       [cell.detailTextLabel setHighlighted:NO];

    return cell;
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

    if(isCellSelected)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_selectedIndexPath];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setHighlighted:NO];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; //added
    isCellSelected = YES;
   _selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
   [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

 }

 @end
```

the out put is somthing like below

[image]

**EDIT OF YOUR CODE**

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   if (indexPath.row != 0)
    {
      if(CellIsSelected)
       {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setHighlighted:NO];
       }

      [self.tableView beginUpdates];

       if ([self datePickerIsShown] && (self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row))            
       {

         [self hideExistingPicker];

       }else {

       NSIndexPath *newPickerIndexPath = [self calculateIndexPathForNewPicker:indexPath];
       if ([self datePickerIsShown])
        {
           [self hideExistingPicker];
           selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
           if (newPickerIndexPath.row == 2)
              selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:indexPath.section];
           else if (newPickerIndexPath.row == 3)
              selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:indexPath.section];
        }
        else
           selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

       [self showNewPickerAtIndex:newPickerIndexPath];
       self.datePickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newPickerIndexPath.row + 1 inSection:0];

   }
   [self.tableView endUpdates];
   [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   CellIsSelected = YES;
   [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
   [picker reloadAllComponents];

   }
 }
```

Comment: Same Effect...It doesn´t stay highlighted...I think that [self.tableVIew deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; is setting it back...

Comment: @chrizstone sorry for late, i posted the entire project   check it out comment if there is any problem

Comment: It´s not working for me...In your example you don´t have  [self.tableVIew deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

Comment: @chrizstone check now